# How do I interpret ASCII values of characters of a string as chars in C?

Tags: c, string, formatting, char, ascii

I have a sequence of numbers representing ASCII values of alphabet characters [A,Z], [a,z] and " ". I can get in a char the ascii value of one of the values (i.e. char = 76), but when I try to make the boundaries checking and the appending to the result I can't seem to get "L" instead of 76 and cant compare the char value to the ASCII values of the boundaries (i.e A = 65). How do I do this in C?

```
//input would be something like char* source = "76111114..."
// result should be "Lor"
for(int i = 0; i < strLen; i+=2)
{
    char actualChar = ' ';
    
    //get two numbers as a character
    strncpy(&actualChar, source + i, 2);
    
    //this prints out 76
    printf("%s\n", &actualChar);

    //this prints out 55
    printf("%d\n", actualChar);
    
    
    //check if the character is a space
    if(actualChar == 32)
    {
        //append
         strncat(result, &actualChar, 2);
         printf("Added space : %s\n", result);
         continue;
    }
    
    //[A, Z]
    else if(actualChar >= 65 && actualChar <= 90)
    {
        //append
        strncat(result, &actualChar, 2);
        printf("Added 2 digit char: %s, %s\n", &actualChar ,result);
        continue;
    }
    
    else
    {
        //add one number to the char and check again
        strncpy(&actualChar, source + i, 3);
        
        //[a, z]
        if(actualChar >= 97 && actualChar <= 122)
        {
            ++i;
            
            //append
            strncat(result, &actualChar, 3);
            printf("Added 3 digit char: %s, %s\n", &actualChar ,result);
            
            continue;
        }
        
        //not a valid char
        else
        {
            printf("Not valid char: %s", &actualChar);
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

I would like result to be "Lor" but instead I am getting "76111114".

Comment: Please make a [mre] to demonstrate the symptoms of "I can't seem to get "L" instead of 76".

Comment: @Yunnosch at the top pf the code, in the comments there is the input and the expected output. I don't know if that would be enough

Comment: You're trying to copy up to 2 characters into a one-character variable.  Can you see why that's a problem?

Comment: @Jabberwocky wouldn't that just get one number per iteration? (i.e. actualChar = 7, actualChar = 6, actualChar = 1, etc. for each of the iterations)

Comment: @TomKarzes I guess it is a problem, but then how can I reinterpret those two (or three) digits as a single character?

Comment: A much better way of approaching this problem would be with code like `sscanf(source, "%2d", &actualChar)` and `sscanf(source, "%3d", &actualChar)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, `sscanf(source, "%2d", &actualChar) and sscanf(source, "%3d", &actualChar)`is the easiest way to get it, although I had to cast actualChar it to `int*` for the sscanf to work:

`sscanf(source+ i, "%2d", (int*)(&actualChar));`